# Detecting Collisions With Two Animated Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using CSS animations to move two rectangle div tags across the screen. Each one is like a pole (taller than it is wide). The animations make each div rotate so it is at an angle before going back to pointing upwards.
One animation is triggered by the user, and the other is constantly moving itself towards the other div.

I have tried using getBoundingClientRect() to detect when the corner of one div intercepts the div that is moving towards it. I also used jQuery to get the .position() of them, but they return left: 0.

The div that is moving across the screen is done using the margin-left property.

Are there any methods I should be looking into or does anyone have a solution to a similar problem?

Thanks,
DH

Comment: Impossible. `Element.getBoundingClientRect().left` will return the element left value. Also, *don't* use margins to move elements.

Comment: Okay, I am switching to using style.left to move them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transform: translate` to move them.

Also, since you're moving the elements in javascript you should just keep their state stored in memory and do your collision detection entirely in javascript.

There should be no need to use DOM APIs for this.

Comment: Thank you, it is a shame their is no API for this. I will be doing the collision detection in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There's no method on the DOM for you to be able to detect overlapping objects. I would suggest using a geometric model of the scene and doing the trigonometry yourself to see when there is an intersection between the two boxes. Animating your objects explicitly using JS is also easier, since you wouldn't have to worry about getting out of sync with the browser's CSS animations or transitions.

You'd basically be looking for a [line-line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line).

Comment: Thank you. I am moving them with JS, and using CSS for the rotation. I reckon I could do the trig idea using the angle and length to work out the tips of both. Thanks again!